# Почему при использовании метода groupby в pandas колонки по которым происходит группировка исчезают из расчета?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

К примеру есть таблица:

[image]

Её размерность — (6, 3).

После применения groupby:

```
df_gr = df.groupby(['Towns', 'Country']).sum()
```

[image: После группировки]

Её размерность — (6, 1)

Что из себя представляют "Country" и "Towns" столбцы?
Как они связаны с DataFrame?

Comment: Это мультииндекс. Именно так реализуется механизм группировки. Вы можете либо отказаться от использования столбцов, по которым делаете группировку в качестве индекса, либо позже сделать индекс "одноуровневым".

Comment: И еще. примеры данных в вопросе должны быть в текстовом виде.

Comment: Одноуровневым - это означает таким же столбцом (атрибутом) как и остальные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете отказаться использовать столбцы, по которым делаете группировку, в качестве индекса, например так:

```
df.groupby(['country','towns'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Либо "сбросить" индекс:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Спасибо
Просто когда я использую функцию .map
Например в случае:

'data_all.longitude[data_all.longitude==0.0] = data_all[data_all.longitude==0.0].subvillage.map(
    average_coords_subvillage['longitude']
)'

,где average_coords_subvillage['longitude'] - это одноразмерная таблица, однако по признаку subvillage как раз и выполняется .map
 
а "subvillage" входит в состав  average_coords_subvillage, но в качестве (как вы сказали) индекса

И вот будет ли всё это работать если я уберу индексирование?

Comment: Формировани еaverage_coords_subvillage: 
average_coords_subvillage = data_all[data_all.longitude!=0].groupby('subvillage')[['longitude', 'latitude']].mean()

Comment: Будет ли это все работать? Это зависит от ваших задач. Смысл мультииндекса в том, что он связывает вfшу выборку по двум колонкам, то есть делает именно то, что вы и просили от pandas. В любом случае, вы можете работать и с мультииндексом, без преобразований. Если же вы сбросите индекс, то при выборке значений вам снова придется делать это по условию.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь  Буду детальнее разбираться с понятием "мультииндекс" и экспериментирлвать